# How to Fetch Specific Datas From Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

```
[
  Beacons:[    
    Beacons1:[
        heritage:"Heritage Point1" 
        uuid:"qwerty"   
        ]   
    Beacons2:[
        heritage:"Heritage Point2"
        uuid:"asdfgh"
        ]
  ]

  Heritage Point1: [
          Title:"India"
          location:[
                lat:"11.345234"
                lon:"35.643521"
                ]
           Description:"Democratic Country"
  ]
]
```

This is the Firebase Model!!!
I have uuid I need to fetch datas from specific heritage points1
from my Beacons Loop how its Possible..
I know only fetching single values.
 Here is My Code!!

```
   'let rootRef = Database.database().reference()

    rootRef.child("Beacons").observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in

    guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }

   let uuidDatas = dictionary["uuid"] as? String

   let heritageDatas = dictionary["heritage"] as? String

        print("uuidData: \(uuidDatas ?? "")")
        print("HeritageData: \(heritageDatas ?? "")")

  })'
```

***Output***

```
uuidData: Optional("qwerty")
HeritageData: Heritage Point1
uuidData: Optional("asdfgh")
HeritageData: Heritage Point2
```

***Anyone Please to help me to get Heritage Point Datas
I'm using swift 4 language***

Comment: The question is pretty unclear; With your structure and code, you're iterating over all of the child nodes of Beacons - as shown by your output. Are you asking how to query for a particular node? There is no 'Beacons Loop' per-say, other than using .childAdded to iterate over all of the nodes. Can you clarify what you are asking? What data are you actually trying to get?

Answer (score 1):

Please fix your question format first as it is really hard to read and understand what you are trying to do in your code.

If you want to get a specific item in the Firebase Database, this example might help you:

```
// somebody try this if we can have space in-between Heritage and point1
let myDatabaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Beacons/Heritage Point1")

myDatabaseRef.observe(.value) { (snap:DataSnapshot) in 

    // Do whatever you want with your snapshot here
    print(snap.value)
}
```

or follow along this tutorial from their official YouTube Page:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joVi3thZOqc&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLn-elkHPhDuuwdCZ93BXnrB&index=19